# Deleted tasks are being retrieved using the query .net Rest API

Tags: c#, rally

I just deleted a task using the Rally website, but when a search for task using the REST API it doesn't return it. I assumed that it should return with the flag "Recycled".

Can anybody help me?

Regards,
Paulo

Answer (score 1):

This is an inconsistency in the WSAPI.  Unfortunately all queries are implicitly scoped (Recycled = false) so nothing that has been deleted will ever be returned from the artifact endpoints.  There is also no way to access the contents of the recycle bin through the WSAPI.

I would encourage you to vote for the idea for this functionality at https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D2374.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not ideal, you can get to the Recycle Bin through this REST endpoint:

`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/recyclebin.js?workspace=/workspace/12345678910&project=/project/12345678911`

Where the long integers the Workspace and Project OID's of interest.

Recycle bin entries look like the following:

```
{
    _rallyAPIMajor: "1",
    _rallyAPIMinor: "40",
    _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/recyclebinentry/12345678910.js",
    _refObjectName: "Test Case 3: Load in, run Analysis on Integer Grids",
    _type: "RecycleBinEntry"
}
```

Where the Recycle Bin OID is unique and different from the OID of the Artifact that was deleted, so there's not a good way to map the Recycle Bin Entry to the Artifact that was deleted to create it. The Object Name could work, although you run the risk of duplicates. The Recycle Bin Entries also come with the same limitations as does the Recycle Bin in the UI - child objects are not shown/accessible.

If you want to walk the Recycle Bin from .NET, here's a quick example:

```
 namespace RestExample_QueryRecycleBin  {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;

            String userName = "user@company.com";
            String userPassword = "topsecret";

            // Set Rally parameters
            String rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String rallyWSAPIVersion = "1.40";

            //Initialize the REST API
            restApi = new RallyRestApi(userName,
                                       userPassword,
                                       rallyURL,
                                       rallyWSAPIVersion);

            // Specify workspace and project
            string myWorkspace = "/workspace/12345678910";
            string myProject = "/project/12345678911";

            //Query for items

            Request request = new Request("recyclebinentry");
            request.Workspace = myWorkspace;
            request.Project = myProject;

            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

            foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
            {
                //Process item
                string itemName = result["_refObjectName"];
                string itemRef = result["_ref"];
                Console.WriteLine(itemRef + ", " + itemName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```